# What are the benefits of listening these mantras?

Tags: vedas, mantras, yajur-veda, krishna-yajurveda

What are the benefits of listening the mantra present in 6.1.1 of Krishna Yajur Veda Samhita (Pavayati Chitpatistva Punaatvityah....) and Medha Suktam.

Also, provide some details about MedhaSuktam.